# cocoa: what's the meaning of NSbutton sender intValue?

Tags: cocoa

I create a IBAction like the following:

```
- (IBAction)okButton:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"%d",[sender intValue]);
}
```

when I repeatedly click the button, the code print out  1,0,1,0,1,0. I want to know the meaning of intValue of a sender.
The reference is Returns the receiver’s value as an int.
 but I don't know what doesn't it 's meaning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That would be the NSButton state which is an NSInteger, but you should use this enum instead:

```
enum {
   NSMixedState = -1,
   NSOffState   = 0,
   NSOnState    = 1
};
```

The button will usually be in `NSOffState` until you click it and it changes to `NSOnState`, then the next click changes it back again - for a simple button you don't see this state visually but for some button types (like a checkbox) the state is displayed visually.

The `sender` here will be your `NSButton`, and it would be more correct to use `state` rather than `intValue` (but you'd need to cast it to `NSButton` first).

Comment: is there any difference between using NSOnState/NSOffState and just the numbers 1/0?

Comment: The difference is clarity, `NSOnState` documents your code. Otherwise no.